# Trying to install refinery cms ror gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

I am trying to install refiny cms:

I wrote

```
rails new my_new_application -m http://refinerycms.com/t/edge
cd my_new_application
rails server
```

And got this:

> The git source https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application
>   I run

```
bundle install
```

And got this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.2) was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
      railties (= 4.0.2) was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
        actionpack (= 4.0.2)

    rails (= 4.0.2) was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
      railties (= 4.0.2) was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
        actionpack (= 4.0.2)

    rails (= 4.0.2) was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
      railties (= 4.0.2) was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
        actionpack (= 4.0.2)

    refinerycms was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
      refinerycms-core (= 3.0.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
        actionpack (< 5.0, >= 4.2.3)
```

I am really new to rails. How do I fix this?

Upd:
As suggested I changed my gem file: and added gem 'refinerycms'

This is my complete gemfile now:

```
   source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

#gem 'refinerycms', git: 'https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms', branch: 'master'

gem 'quiet_assets', group: :development

# Add support for searching inside Refinery's admin interface.
gem 'refinerycms-acts-as-indexed', ['~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.0']

# Add support for Refinery's custom fork of the visual editor WYMeditor.
gem 'refinerycms-wymeditor', ['~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.6']

# The default authentication adapter
gem 'refinerycms-authentication-devise', '~> 1.0'
gem 'refinerycms'
```

When I ran `bundle install` I still get the following error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.2) was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
      railties (= 4.0.2) was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
        actionpack (= 4.0.2)

    rails (= 4.0.2) was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
      railties (= 4.0.2) was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
        actionpack (= 4.0.2)

    rails (= 4.0.2) was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
      railties (= 4.0.2) was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
        actionpack (= 4.0.2)

refinerycms-wymeditor (>= 1.0.6, ~> 1.0) was resolved to 1.0.6, which depends
on
      refinerycms-core (>= 3.0.0, ~> 3.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
        actionpack (< 5.0, >= 4.2.3)

    rails (= 4.0.2) was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0) was resolved to 2.0.1, which depends on
        actionpack (>= 3.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is due to version incompatibility between rails , refinerycms and actionpack . If you are not much concerned about the refinerycms version to be used in you app , then you can just create a new rails application and add the following in your Gemfile :-

```
gem 'refinerycms'
```

This would resolve the dependencies and install the refinery version compatible with your rails version :)

Comment: Can you update rails to gem 'rails', '4.2.3' ? I am assuming you have just started building a new app . Just create a rails app with this command - rails _4.2.3_ new myapp and then add refinerycms to the gemfile after that .

Comment: sorry but when I type rails `4.2.3 new myapp `it tells me `Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]` and long list of options

Comment: There has to be an underscore before and after 4.2.3 , not able to post on stackoverflow as it doesn't allows me to put that in comments

Comment: @user2950593 Can you select this as the right answer if it helped you ?